# Pydantic Type with arbitrary type list in it

Tags: python, fastapi, python-3.8, pydantic

I have defined a standard API response Pydantic type as follows:

```py
class ApiResponse(BaseModel):
    success: bool
    data: Optional[List[Any]] = []
    message: Optional[str] = None
    meta: Optional[dict] = {}
```

However, the `data` list will be a list of pre-defined Pydantic types, depending on the endpoint. For example, if the endpoint is `/users`, I want Pydantic to enforce that the `data` list must be a list of `User` objects. I attempted to modify the `ApiResponse` class as follows:

```py
class User(BaseModel):
    name: str
    favorite_sandwich: str

class ApiResponse(SubType):
    success: bool
    data: Optional[List[SubType]] = []
    message: Optional[str] = None
    meta: Optional[dict] = {}
```

I then want to be able to define the endpoint with:

```py
@router.get("/users", response_model=ApiResponse[User])
async def get_groups() -> ApiResponse[User]:
    users = models.User.all()
    count = models.User.count()
    return {"success" : True, "data": users, "meta" : {"count": count}}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is. That is what [**generics**](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#user-defined-generic-types) in general and [**generic models**](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/models/#generic-models) in particular are for.

You create a [type variable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar) `M` (for example) and set its upper bound to `BaseModel`, then define a `GenericModel` class parameterized by that type variable and annotate its `data` field with `List[M]`

Example:

```py
from typing import Any, Dict, Generic, List, Optional, TypeVar

from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from pydantic.generics import GenericModel

M = TypeVar("M", bound=BaseModel)


class ApiResponse(GenericModel, Generic[M]):
    success: bool
    data: List[M] = Field(default_factory=list)
    message: Optional[str] = None
    meta: Dict[str, Any] = Field(default_factory=dict)


class User(BaseModel):
    name: str
    favorite_sandwich: str


class Point2D(BaseModel):
    x: float
    y: float
```

Then you can define your routes like this for example:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI

# ... import ApiResponse, Point2D, User


app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/users", response_model=ApiResponse[User])
async def get_groups() -> Dict[str, Any]:
    users = [
        User(name="Alice", favorite_sandwich="BLT"),
        User(name="Bob", favorite_sandwich="Ham&Cheese"),
    ]
    count = len(users)
    return {
        "success": True,
        "data": users,
        "meta": {"count": count},
    }


@app.get("/points")
async def get_points() -> ApiResponse[Point2D]:
    points = [Point2D(x=3.14, y=0), Point2D(x=-100.1, y=420.69)]
    return ApiResponse(success=True, data=points)
```

Sending `GET` requests to those endpoints yields the following response bodies:

```json
{
  "success": true,
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Alice",
      "favorite_sandwich": "BLT"
    },
    {
      "name": "Bob",
      "favorite_sandwich": "Ham&Cheese"
    }
  ],
  "message": null,
  "meta": {
    "count": 2
  }
}
```

```json
{
  "success": true,
  "data": [
    {
      "x": 3.14,
      "y": 0
    },
    {
      "x": -100.1,
      "y": 420.69
    }
  ],
  "message": null,
  "meta": null
}
```

If you check the JSON Schemas generated for those endpoints, you'll see that the type arguments are properly resolved and the `data` list element schemas are different for the two endpoints.

---

**Side notes**:

- Your initial `ApiResponse` model defined both `data` and `meta` as `Optional`, but your default values corresponded to the "actual" field types (i.e. `list` and `dict` respectively). `Optional[T]` is equivalent to `Union[T, None]`. So unless you *actually* want `None` to be allowed as a value for those fields, I suggest getting rid of the `Optional` there. Setting default values already makes the fields non-required. (see my example)
- Also, when dealing with mutable types like `list` or `dict`, it is *probably* a good idea (or at least good form) to use the [`default_factory`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/models/#field-with-dynamic-default-value) pattern instead of assigning the default value.
- When the return type of your route handler function actually matches your desired response model (as in my `points` route for example), you can omit the `response_model` argument to the route decorator and simply annotate the function itself with it. When it *doesn't* match (as in `users`), you should still correctly annotate the return type (in that example `Dict[str, Any]`), but provide the correct `response_model` in the decorator. (see [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/#response_model-parameter) for details)

Comment: This is incredibly helpful, thank you! I have couple more questions. What is the value in using the default factory to generate the list? Is there some use case where how I did it would yield unexpected results? Also when you say in your example that the `/users` endpoint doesn't match the response model, I don't see how. Can you clarify?

Comment: I meant that the route handler function associated with the `/users` endpoint actually has a `dict` return type. It returns a dictionary with the data that is used to _construct_ a `ApiResponse[User]` object. Because of that it is necessary to specify the `response_model` in the decorator. The `/points` function actually returns an `ApiResponse[Point2D]` object. I just used that to show the distinction. In your original code you mistakenly annotated the function with the return type `ApiResponse`. As for the `default_factory` I am not 100% sure, I'll have to test it.